# What to use in UML when a class does not have inheritance relationship with other classes

Tags: uml, relationship, class-diagram

If I have a person class that has an array list of documents as a field and document is completely separate class, how would I represent this kind of relationship in UML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Association defines a relationship between classes of objects that allows one object instance to cause another to perform an action on its behalf. Usually used if Object own other Object 
In your case (association) is good option because person  is the owner & person can write document

Comment: If there is another scenario, where and Employee has documents (as in previously) and then the Employer has a method that allows him to assign documents to Employees (Employer does not have any fields with documents but he has an assign method that uses a Document as a parameter) would this also be an association between Employer and the Document class?

Comment: @domke89 Bad habit to start serial questions in comment. Use separate new questions instead. Anyhow, this would just be a dependency.

Comment: Yes sure,because classes is representation of real world scenario , I mean you can't assign something you don't have.

Comment: @Prof.Mo: An association between `Person` and `Document` classifies relationships between persons and documents (these relationships are called "links" in UML). Why should an association "allow one object instance to cause another to perform an action on its behalf"? What do you mean with "cause"?

Comment: @Gerd Wagner Link relationship is an instance of an association .Why should an association. This general definition of association , It's mean ownership but in more general form ,let me explain sometimes  I have case non static Object like Employees and Employers there relationship could be inheritance what if Inheritance not need such they have totally different role but what if there special case that employee should finish employer task   here we can make  association relationship between them because there's no inheritance and there still relationship

Comment: @Gerd Wagner An association is a specification of a collection of links,While Link is theoretical and physical connection between objects.In this case it's more likely to be association bacause it'more general I am not giving specific document so there are a lot of possible links.

Comment: @Prof.Mo: Please improve your English for being able to express yourself. Also, try to avoid using too much prosa (like "theoretical and physical connection" and "more likely to be") and get to the point.

Comment: @Gerd Wagner Sorry for English mistakes. I got these prosa from OOP book and articles it's mention a lot .

Comment: @Gerd Wagner I am writing a comments from mobile . But any way can you please explain why you believe it's Link not  Association. Then I am going to edit the answer.

Comment: https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-link-and-association.html. You can find what I actually mean in the textbook ( The Elements of UML Style) page 100,101